# Javascript: Could access object and show it, but not a valid property of that object?

Tags: javascript

My console message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined.

However, when I log to the console the `snake.head` object, it gives me a valid "response"! How could it be that an object is defined but when trying to store a property of that object in a variable it doesn't work? I also tried just continuing the game without storing the x and y position in a variable and instead accessing it within the head object and guess what? Doesn't work. I even tried just accessing the `game.SNAKE[game.SNAKE.length-1].(property)` but it also doesn't work! However, when I try it in my `snake.init` function, it works fine, but I can't do this, as my init only runs once!

```
var game = {};

game.contextBackground = document.getElementById("bgCanvas").getContext("2d");
game.contextSnake = document.getElementById("snakeCanvas").getContext("2d");
game.contextFruit = document.getElementById("fruitCanvas").getContext("2d");

game.keys = [];
game.SNAKE = [];

game.width = document.getElementById("snakeCanvas").width;
game.height = document.getElementById("snakeCanvas").height;


game.COLUMNS = 35;
game.ROWS = 35;
game.boxSide = game.width/game.COLUMNS;



game.snake = {

    snakeLength: 3,
    tailx: null,
    taily: null,
    head: null,
    headx: null,
    heady: null,
    direction: "right",

    createSnake: function (snakeLength) {
        game.SNAKE.length = this.snakeLength;
        for (i=0;i<snakeLength;i++) {
            game.SNAKE[i] = {
                x: i ,
                y: 0
            };
        }
    },

    updateSnake: function (length) {
        this.head = game.SNAKE[length-1];
        this.headx = this.head.x;
        for (i in game.SNAKE) {

        }
    },

    init: function() {
        this.createSnake(this.snakeLength);


    },

    update: function() {
        this.updateSnake(game.SNAKE.length);
        console.log(this.head);
        for (i in game.SNAKE) {
            game.SNAKE[i].x ++;
        }
    },


    render: function() {
        game.contextSnake.clearRect(0,0,game.width,game.height);
        for (i in game.SNAKE) {
            drawBox(game.SNAKE[i].x,game.SNAKE[i].y,game.contextSnake,"green");
        }
    }
};

game.fruit = {

    x: null,
    y: null,
    newFruitNecessary: true,

    init: function() {

    },

    update: function() {

    },

    render: function() {

    }
};

function init() {
    loop();
    game.snake.init();
    game.fruit.init();
}

function update() {
    game.snake.update();
    game.fruit.update();
}

function render() { 
    game.fruit.render();
    game.snake.render();
}

function loop() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        loop();
    },1000/10);

    update();
    render();
} 

function drawBox (gridx,gridy,context,color) {
    if (color == null) {
        color = "black";
    }

    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect((gridx * game.boxSide), (gridy * game.boxSide), game.boxSide,game.boxSide);
}

init();
```

Comment: It's confusing to have both `game.snake` and `game.SNAKE`. Don't do that.

Comment: which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Are you talking about the `update:` method? Where you used logged `this.head` and then used `game.SNAKE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `init` your snake (and later fruit) before you can loop; otherwise, `game.SNAKE` will point at an empty array, so the lines

```
this.head = game.SNAKE[length-1];
this.headx = this.head.x;
```

will fail to work properly when the first `update()` calls inside your `loop()`. `game.SNAKE` is empty, so you store `undefined` to `this.head`; thus, `this.head.x` resolves to `undefined.x`, which fails.

Try shifting around the lines in `init`:

```
function init() {
    game.snake.init();
    game.fruit.init();
    loop();
}
```

Comment: Nice catch... sounds like a student project. Reminds me of my old "be the computer" assignments.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I just realized that. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! If you found my answer useful, please accept it by ticking the green checkmark.